# Use tf.data.Dataset direct form .npz file

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, ram, tensorflow-datasets

I have `115GB .npz` file.
It is possible to create tf.data.Dataset directly from this file to avoid 115GB RAM allocation?

According to:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy

First step is to load file into np array:
`np_arr = np.load(path)` with require a lot of RAM. Then the `tf.data.Dataset` is created:
`train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np_arr)`

How pass `.npz` file directly to tf.data.Dataset avoiding declaration of numpy array?

Comment: If `path` really is a `.npz` file, `np_arr` will be a `dict` like object, which shouldn't take up much memory.  It's a lazy-loader.  You have to use `np.arr[name]` to actually load an array.  But I don't know if `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` can handle that dict, or whether it has to work with an array.

Answer (score 0):

From your link

```
DATA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz'

path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('mnist.npz', DATA_URL)
with np.load(path) as data:
  train_examples = data['x_train']
  train_labels = data['y_train']
  test_examples = data['x_test']
  test_labels = data['y_test']

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_examples, train_labels))
```

`data` is the `npz` `dict`, while `traion_examples` is the actual array.  It does not pass `data` directly to the `tensor_slices`.

Comment: still `data` and `train_dataset` require RAM to allocate in memory

Comment: `npy` files allow a `memmap` mode load, but `npz` don't.  Anyways, I more familiar with the `numpy` end of this.  I don't use `tensorflow`, so can't tell you anymore than what I can see reading the docs.  I don't see any evidence that its `slices` can work directly with a `npy` file.  `numpy` can't load portions (except via the memmap mode).